# NUnit: how to unit test that another unit test fails?

Tags: c#, nunit

I have a wrapper like this.

```
    public static void ShouldContain(this string str, string subStr)
    {
        Assert.That(str, Contains.Substring(subStr));
    }
```

Is it possible to unit test this wrapper?
I was able to unit test that it passes, by adding a TestCase attribute:

```
    [TestCase("Hello world","world", 
        Description= "This test case will pass, because the Assert will be successful")]
    public static void ShouldContain(this string str, string subStr)
    {
        Assert.That(str, Contains.Substring(subStr));
    }
```

But when I tried another TestCase, which was negative, my negative TestCase failed, because of the failing Assert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to test it using `ExpectedException` parameter of TestCase attribute:

```
    [TestCase("Hello world","world")]
    [TestCase("Hello world", "bye", ExpectedException = typeof(AssertionException))]
    public static void ShouldContain(this string str, string subStr)
    {
        Assert.That(str, Contains.Substring(subStr));
    }
```

Comment: This approach only works well as long as you only have one assertion per test. If you have more than one you do not longer know which one failed. You could add a third boolean parameter if `str` should contain `substr` or not and write your assertion on that.

Comment: @DMAN, thank you for your comment. The function `ShouldContain()` is supposed to be used in other unit tests, so I would not like adding a parameter. By the way, many believe there should be only [one assertion per test](http://programmaticallyspeaking.com/one-assertion-per-test-please.html)